# No events are generated in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events

There is a js file that is built using the **Laravel Mix**. It previously had 2 components, after which there was a need to register a new one. After I registered all the necessary logic, I decided to launch it. Assembled bundle. I check. Does not respond to pressing. Everything is correct in the code. There were no errors during assembly. The developer console is also empty. I decided to just write **console.log**. You never know. Nothing helped. As a result, I made a copy of *current_ source.vue*, and in the original I erased everything and wrote simply

```
<template>
<v-btn @click="console.log('adfesfwf')">ajvarhe</v-btn>
</template>
```

Yes, yes, I have Vuetify connected. Buttons are correctly displayed, but in the console, by pressing, it is empty. At the same time, I use DevTools for Vue, where it is very convenient to view dispatched events. For all the time debugging this error, not a single event was recorded. At the same time, hooks work (checked only **created**). I tried to create a completely different component. Exactly the same problem. I want to draw attention to the fact that the previous 2 components work correctly. How many rebuilds were there, events work.

Comment: Can you create a minimal, reproducible example of the behavior? Either a git repo or a codepen/stackblitz?

Comment: i believe @click="console.log()" is the same as this.console.log() where this refers to the vue instance, so it is probably undefined. Vue Devtools only displays events emitted by Vue.$emit not by dom.

Comment: You need to put console.log inside a vue method to work

Comment: When I tried to upload everything to CodePen, the error "Cannot read property 'log' of undefined" popped up. However, the full download failed due to the large bundle size. That is, the events worked out on CodePen. I tried to make a call in a separate method. I understand that Vue DevTools may not display all events. But after all, let it not display them, but something should be written to the console.

Comment: Also, it is very strange and wonderful that in the other 2 components of this file everything works fine. No complaints.

Comment: I want to note that I'm not new to this. That is, there is already some experience, but here simply out of the blue the elementary does not work.

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad english

Comment: @Tanner *Comment for Notification*

Comment: @ChrisLi *Comment for Notification*

Comment: @HansC.FelixRamos *Comment for Notification*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to subscribe to a native event, you must use a special modifier `native`. 
In your case, it will look like this  `<v-btn @click.native="console.log('adfesfwf')">ajvarhe</v-btn>`